# AG Grid make pinned left columns have a max width and scrollable

Tags: javascript, css, ag-grid

There is an issue with ag grid pinning columns, if you pin too many columns it will fill the grid to where you cant see any of the unpinned data. There is no viable solution available in ag grids core functionality.
In my particular scenario I have like 30-40 columns and users may want to pin a lot of these to help them compare data against what they don't have pinned as they scroll in either the pinned on non pinned data

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/SGydEpznhYUuxmBd)

You can see it here in the demo if you drag one more column to the pinned and on any of the official ag grid documentation with working examples it can be replicated.

just need the most basic of aggrid with alot of columns to reproduce

```
<AgGridReact
          modules={this.state.modules}
          columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
          defaultColDef={this.state.defaultColDef}
          debug={true}
          rowData={this.state.rowData}
          onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get a pretty dam hackey solution to this problem

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/GMqgvQjRsC5Tqf0C)

The first thing to note is that because of how hacky this solution is it can break existing ag grid core functionality and will only really work with aggrid paging enabled

```
pagination={true}
paginationAutoPageSize={true}
```

we need to wrap each section inside the grid in our own containers

```
    //wrap the pinned left header area
    var headerParent = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-header')[0];
    var headerChild = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-pinned-left-header')[0];
    var newHeaderContainer = document.createElement('div');
    newHeaderContainer.id = 'header-container';
    newHeaderContainer.className = 'header-container';
    // set the newDivContainer as child (instead of the element)
    headerParent.replaceChild(newHeaderContainer, headerChild);
    // set element as child of newDivContainer
    newHeaderContainer.appendChild(headerChild);


    //wrap the pinned left Data area
    var dataParent = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-body-viewport')[0];
    var dataChild = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-pinned-left-cols-container')[0];
    var newDataContainer = document.createElement('div');
    newDataContainer.id = 'data-container';
    newDataContainer.className = 'data-container';
    // set the newDivContainer as child (instead of the element)
    dataParent.replaceChild(newDataContainer, dataChild);
    // set element as child of newDivContainer
    newDataContainer.appendChild(dataChild);   


    //wrap the non pinned data area
    var unpinnedDataParent = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-center-cols-viewport')[0];
    var unpinnedDataChild = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-center-cols-container')[0];
    var newUnpinnedDataContainer = document.createElement('div');
    newUnpinnedDataContainer.id = 'unpinned-data-container';
    newUnpinnedDataContainer.className = 'unpinned-data-container';
    // set the newDivContainer as child (instead of the element)
    unpinnedDataParent.replaceChild(newUnpinnedDataContainer, unpinnedDataChild);
    // set element as child of newDivContainer
    newUnpinnedDataContainer.appendChild(unpinnedDataChild);


    //wrap the non pinned header area
    var unpinnedHeaderParent = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-header-viewport')[0];
    var unpinnedHeaderChild = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-header-container')[0];
    var newUnpinnedHeaderContainer = document.createElement('div');
    newUnpinnedHeaderContainer.id = 'unpinned-header-container';
    newUnpinnedHeaderContainer.className = 'unpinned-header-container';
    // set the newDivContainer as child (instead of the element)
    unpinnedHeaderParent.replaceChild(newUnpinnedHeaderContainer, unpinnedHeaderChild);
    // set element as child of newDivContainer
    newUnpinnedHeaderContainer.appendChild(unpinnedHeaderChild);
```

because these are separate entities that can scroll individually connect them with event listeners to scroll at the same time

```
document.getElementsByClassName('data-container')[0].addEventListener("scroll", this.runOnScroll1, { passive: true });
document.getElementsByClassName('unpinned-data-container')[0].addEventListener("scroll", this.runOnScroll2, { passive: true });
```

and their corresponding functions they call

```
runOnScroll1=  function(evt) {
document.getElementsByClassName('header-container')[0].scrollTo(evt.srcElement.scrollLeft, 0)};
runOnScroll2=  function(evt) {
document.getElementsByClassName('unpinned-header-container')[0].scrollTo(evt.srcElement.scrollLeft, 0)};
```

Finally you need to set and override a bunch of css styles to our new containers and some of the grids classes

```
    .ag-body-viewport{
        overflow: hidden !important;
    }
    .ag-header {
        height: 55px !important;
    }
    .data-container {
        min-width: 50% !important;
        max-width: 50% !important;
        width: 50% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
        overflow-x: scroll !important;
        overflow-y: hidden !important;
    }
    .unpinned-data-container {
        height: 100% !important;
        overflow-y: hidden !important;
        overflow-x: scroll !important;
    }
    .ag-horizontal-left-spacer {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .header-container {
        height: 120px !important;
        width: 50% !important;
        max-width: 50% !important;
        min-width: 50% !important;
        overflow-x: hidden !important;
        overflow-y: hidden !important;
    }
    
    .unpinned-header-container {
        height: 120px !important;
        overflow-y: hidden !important;
        overflow-x: hidden !important;
    }
```